# How to submit a form created with spring form tag using dojo

Tags: javascript, spring, dojo, taglib

I've a form created with spring form tag.

```
<form:form commandName="cmdName" action="save" id="formId">
```

I'm trying to submit this form after validation using Dojo. 
When I use:

```
dijit.byId("formId").submit()
```

I get:

```
TypeError: dijit.byId(...) is undefined
```

in firebug console
and when use:

```
dojo.byId("formId").submit()
```

I get:

```
TypeError: dojo.byId(...).submit is not a function
```

While searching, i found a similiar problem here.

[Appfuse](http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/Spring-2-0-Form-tags-And-Javascript-submit-td562601.html)

Comment: there is a difference between dijit.byId & dojo.byId ! I think dijit.byId is for accessing dijit widgets. Could you setup a fiddle ? Lucian

Comment: The way you're using dojo is right: It must be something with your Dojo configuration. Can you validate if dojo.byId() returns a valid DOM Node?

Comment: @CarlosGavidia dojo.byId() returns the form and all the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding a hidden input submit button to the form. And called the button's click event after validation.

```
<input class="hidden" type="submit" value="" name="submit" id="submitId"/>
```

from script:

```
dojo.byId("submitId").click();
```